# Export python list to already open workbook

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code that generates a python list and I intend to store the results to excel workbook that is already open.
I tried this approach but this works only for closed workbooks

```
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Sample.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Another point, is it possible to deal with xlsm files?

I tried the append approach like that

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("Sample.xlsx", mode="a", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")
```

But still couldn't work on the open workbook. It works only for the closed workbook.

Comment: I think the excel sheet has to be closed, but you can try to change the mode to append `https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you show me an example?

Comment: I doubt that it is possible to write to an open Excel file. An Excel file is a zip container containing interlinked XML files. It isn't like a text file that can be updated externally and then updated automatically or manually in a text editor. An "open" file in Excel probably only exists in application memory until it is saved. Excel does allow simultaneous editing of files via systems like SharePoint but I doubt that can be achieved outside of Excel. Or at the very least is cannot be done wth existing Python tools.